# creating treeview using list as a data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have a list of objects
and i want to bind this list with the treeview control
my class is as follows

```
public class Tax
{
    public string TaxName { get; set; }
    public string TaxPresentationId { get; set; }
    public string ParentTaxName { get; set; }
    public string PresentationTaxName { get; set; }
    public string RoleURl { get; set; }
    public List<Tax> Child { get; set; }

    public Tax()
    {
        Childrens = new List<Tax>();
    }
}
```

I have one list with all the data

```
 List<Tax> lstreportdata = new List<Tax>();
```

how can i bind this list into the treeview control.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use this tree view its a Jquery tree take a data-source and populate a tree http://www.blueshoes.org/_bsJavascript/components/tree/examples/example_json.html

Comment: Yes man for sure but please ans this first

Comment: thanks mehmood but i need to use asp.net treeview control

Comment: Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4fz6xk2(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @jrummell i have used list as a data source but it shows error HierarchicalDataBoundControl only accepts data sources that implement IHierarchicalDataSource or IHierarchicalEnumerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. At least not directly. Take a look at the [TreeView docs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178258%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

The most common usage of a TreeView control is to display site map information, [bound to an XmlDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178367.aspx).

You can also populate it programmatically with the [PopulateOnDemand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.populateondemand%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property.